# Split datetime column in csv file into MM/YYYY and time column separately and write to the same csv

Tags: shell, awk, csv, split, write

I am trying to use awk, split and then print but running into error

Input:

```
id  day userId  itemId

1   12/1/17 8:32    2232    tv

2   1/12/18 10:18   3232    fdfs

3   2/9/18 10:50    232     fdsf

4   3/6/18 12:35    345456  fdg
```

Expected output

```
id  datetime    monthyear   time    userId  itemId

1   12/1/17 8:32    12/17   8:32    2232    tv

2   1/12/18 10:18   1/18    10:18   3232    fdfs

3   2/9/18 10:50    2/18    10:50   232     fdsf

4   3/6/18 12:35    3/18    12:35   345456  fdg
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Care to share the exact command(s) you're trying and _what_ error you're getting?

Comment: What is the field separator in your input file?

Comment: Command used awk -F",", '{OFS=","; split($2,a,"/"); $5=a[1]"/"a[3]; print}' book1.csv >> testbook.csv

Comment: field separator is ,

Comment: error I am getting is awk: illegal statement at source line 1 sometimes awk: bailing out at source line 1 or awk: no program given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
awk -F"\t" '
NR == 1         {$2 = "datetime" OFS "monthyear" OFS "time"
                }
NR > 1          {split ($2, T, "[/ ]")
                 $2 = $2 OFS T[1] "/" T[3] OFS T[4]
                }
1
' OFS="\t" file
id  datetime    monthyear   time    userId  itemId
1   12/1/17 8:32    12/17   8:32    2232    tv
2   1/12/18 10:18   1/18    10:18   3232    fdfs
3   2/9/18 10:50    2/18    10:50   232 fdsf
4   3/6/18 12:35    3/18    12:35   345456  fdg
```

Comment: I run into error awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
 NR == 1         {$2 = >>>  ? <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 2

Comment: What's your OS and `awk` versions? You may want to try `nawk`.

Comment: I am using Mac OS, awk works and I have this code which works to some extent in order to get MM/YYYY however it writes into a new line rather than a new column (I am testing by writing entire content to a new file) awk -F"," '{OFS=FS}{split($2,a,"[/ ]"); $7=a[1]"/"a[3]; print}' book1.csv > testbook.csv

Comment: It worked after I slightly modified the code as below, however in csv the MonthYear was formatted incorrectly. ex: Instead of 12/17 it was 17-Dec (12/17/2018) awk -F "," 'NR == 1 {$2 = "DayTime" OFS "MonthYear" OFS "Time"}{ if (NR>1){split($2,a,"[/ ]");$2=$2;$5=$3;$6=$4;$3=a[1]"/"a[3];$4=a[4]}}1' OFS="," Test.csv > Test1.csv

Answer (score 0):

RudiC shows how to transform the file. To save it back into the same file:

1. using GNU awk:

   ```
   gawk -i inplace '...' file
   ```
2. using [`sponge`](https://manpage.me/?q=sponge) from the `moreutils` package:

   ```
   awk '...' file | sponge file
   ```
3. Or using a temp file

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   awk '...' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
   ```